# FTP download folder with php

Tags: php, ftp

So I was wondering for I can download a intire folder from my FTP server, just by clicking on a `link`. When I have to download my `.log` files from my FTP server I do this:

First I create a link:

```php
function FTP_download($id, $folder = ""){
    ?> <a href="ftp_download.php?folder=<?php echo $folder; ?>&id=<?php echo $id;?>&file=<?php echo $id.'.log'; ?>" download> Download full log </a> <?php
}
```

Then I call the downloader file:

```php
<?php
//Does GET exist
if (!isset($_GET['file'])) {
    echo"ERROR - loading log";
    return false;
}

//Define FTP variables
$ftp_server = "xxxx";
$ftp_user_name = "xxxx";
$ftp_user_pass = "xxxx";
$file = $_GET['file'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$folder = $_GET['folder'];
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);


// Change dir to id folder
ftp_chdir($conn_id, $id);
// Change dir to logs
ftp_chdir($conn_id, $folder);

//Check if file exists
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
$list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '');
if (!in_array($file, $list)) {
    return false;
}


// get the size of $file
$size = ftp_size($conn_id, $file);

//Create headers for force download
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

//Read file content
readfile('ftp://'.$ftp_user_name.':'.urlencode($ftp_user_pass).'@'.$ftp_server.'/'.$id.'/'.$folder.'/'.$file);
ftp_close($conn_id);
return true;
?>
```

By clicking the link, a browser download is started.

[image]

Is it possible to create a download file which downloads the whole folder, with all content in it?

Like download -> `'ftp://'.$ftp_user_name.':'.urlencode($ftp_user_pass).'@'.$ftp_server.'/'.$id.'/'.$folder`

Comment: No. Have you ever seen that anywhere on any page on Internet? A link that would start a download of a folder? – All you can do is what @ObjectName suggested - zip the files in the folder and download the zip. See [How to zip a whole directory and download using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29873248/850848).

Comment: I see, will look into zipping the files then and download that zipped file as I do now with images and .logs thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would do, is downloading all the files in the `/tmp` directory and
then zip them all together into an archive.
This file can then be streamed for as a response.

Make sure though that your tmp directory gets cleared, which normaly php does on its own after the request finished [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131226/php-when-does-the-temporary-uploaded-files-get-deleted).

[PHP ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

If you want to download all files within a single request (not within a folder).
This could work when using the 'Content-Disposition' value as a seperator between the file contents.
I cannot confidently explain you what you would need for that.
Maybe googling for 'mulipart form request' will give you a tutorial on that.

As for creating a direct folder as a response, i have never seen such a feature and don't think it is possible.

In my opinion Zip is the best option here, as it should be supported widely enough,
and keeps your folders intact, wich i think you want to keep.

Comment: There are already many questions covering this: [How to zip a whole directory and download using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29873248/850848).